# Detect if visitor is a browser and not a crawler

Tags: c#, http, browser

How would I server side detect if the user of the webpage is a browser?

The reason for detecting this is, that I'm storing statistics about visited pages and I don't want to store any statistics when the user is a crawler. So I'm not trying to detect which browser vendor. I only want a boolean answer, is the user a browser.

I assume the answer is connected with the user-agent header, but the numerous possibly values is too overwhelming for me to figure out.
How can I detect it? A 90% solution where I only detect the most Top5 popular browser would be good enough.

I'm using C# ASP.Net, but I guess most solutions in other languages and frameworks could be translated.

Comment: As far as I understand, a user is a human, which is using a browser. So a user is never a browser. Do you mean how you can detect which browser users are using?

Comment: "I am not a browser, I'm a free man!"
user->get (coat); user->wear (coat); user->exit (room);

Comment: See "Detecting honest web crawlers" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544450/detecting-honest-web-crawlers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is by no means exhaustive, but gives you a basic founding in PHP. I can't guarantee a few won't slip through the net, but this should catch most browsers and ignore most bots.

```
<?php
// Regular expression to match common browsers
$browserlist = '/(opera|aol|msie|firefox|chrome|konqueror|safari|netscape|navigator|mosaic|lynx|amaya|omniweb|avant|camino|flock|seamonkey|mozilla|gecko)+/i';

// Test for browsers
if (preg_match($browserlist, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    // ...is a browser
} else {
    // ...is not a browser
}
?>
```

Comment: should there not be an 'i' at the end of the preg match to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Very good point! I missed that as I normally `strtolower` the user-agent first.. just fixing

Comment: I don't think this will work, all user agents starts with Mozilla (long and sad story), including many crawlers.

Comment: You'd be correct if we were trying to single out individual browsers, but we're filtering bots. The small amount of research I did for this answer showed that little-to-no bots have "mozilla" in their user-agent string. If you have a list of examples, I'll be more than happy to change the answer

Comment: If you head to http://www.user-agents.org/ there are a number of examples of bots having Mozilla (here's one... http://www.user-agents.org/)

Comment: I am really late to the party but ran into this, is there a way nowaydays, four years later, where we can do this without sniffing the user agent?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP, try [`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/p/http_user_agent.htm) or the [`get_browser()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function.

[Here's a class](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/) that's available for download that makes this process incredibly easy. Example usage:

```
$browser = new Browser();
if( $browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_FIREFOX && $browser->getVersion() >= 2 ) {
 echo 'You have FireFox version 2 or greater';
}
```

Comment: Thats a really good class. Easy to integrate and use, and good features. Really useful, I'm using it to detect incoming Internet Crawlers Robots, and gets the job done pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are doing this.

However, you do not want to even pretend you can tell between a human versus a robot based on the `User-agent` header.  You might be able to get some success analyzing the pattern and timing of requests.

Answer (score 1):

this will give you 99% accuracy.

```
Regex.IsMatch(Request.UserAgent, @"bot|crawler|baiduspider|80legs|ia_archiver|voyager|curl|wget|yahoo! slurp|mediapartners-google", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I've listed more solutions in my answer here:

[Detecting honest web crawlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544450/detecting-honest-web-crawlers)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to decide whether to return (say) raw text for a script versus HTML for a browser, perhaps you should inspect the [Accept-Encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) request header?

Answer (score 0):

Perl has a module [HTTP::BrowserDetect](http://search.cpan.org/~walsham/HTTP-BrowserDetect-0.99/BrowserDetect.pm). According to the docs, this has a method which checks whether a user agent is a robot. Anything which isn't a robot is probably a browser, I guess.

Comment: I think that their both browsers, either Browsers such as Firefox, IE, etc and Robots, because they both browser the page. Just my opinion.