# C# get list bots dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to get bot list dynamic or I need services get bot list for check view without bot crawler.

Like that : [Detecting honest web crawlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544450/detecting-honest-web-crawlers), however I want to get dynamic bot list (latest bots).

Thanks for support,
TuanTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your crawler list from an XML source like http://www.user-agents.org/